# excel, auto sorting/deleting columns that are far apart

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, autocomplete

I have a long list of people with specific criteria, and i need either a macro, or a function in the background that every month when i update this list (delete old and coy paste info in thats new) the columns that are not needed (everything other than B,C,AK,BC) gets deleted and those columns get pushed together. is there any way to do this thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts (this one and http://superuser.com/users/594986/user53965). See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but what you seem to want is to "hide" the unwanted columns.

Simply click on the top of the column letter, then right click and select "hide" and the column will be hidden and the other columns will simply slide over.  ie.  click on column "D" and Excel will highlight the entire column, then right click and a menu will pop up.  Select "hide" and column "D" will disappear and columns C and E will slide together.

The data is still there and can be displayed again if you select the line between columns C and E and right click, and then select "unhide" from the pop up menu.

Hope this helps.....
P.S. If you use the shift key while selecting the columns, you can select several adjacent columns.   If you use the "Ctrl" key while selecting columns you can select several columns even if they are not adjacent.